# Wireshark - Finding HTTP and application layer payload from a given pcap file

Tags: wireshark

I am trying to trying to get the packets which contain application layer payloads like HTTP from a given pcap file.

I have tried using http in the Wireshark display filter. My doubt is that, is it the right way to get the http payload from the pcap file. Please help me on this.

Comment: "I am trying to trying to get the packets which contain application layer payloads like HTTP from a given pcap file." => What does your desired output look like? What does "Getting" the packets mean?

Comment: i have all packets in pcap file. from it, i need to identify which packets contain http payload and i need to store it in another pcap file

Answer (score 1):

### Saving HTTP packets

To filter for http traffic in tshark, you would use a [display filter](https://tshark.dev/analyze/packet_hunting/packet_hunting/) (`-Y`). This is sample output showing what that would look like:

```sh
$ tshark -r input.pcap -Y http
   25   1.051399 10.8.143.109 → server-13-35-127-122.sfo5.r.cloudfront.net HTTP
630 GET /online HTTP/1.1  0c:8d:db:90:cf:38 ← 6c:96:cf:d8:7f:e7
   34   1.078368 server-13-35-127-122.sfo5.r.cloudfront.net → 10.8.143.109 HTTP
404 HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified  6c:96:cf:d8:7f:e7 ← 0c:8d:db:90:cf:38
```

This shows them output as text (the default). To output them to a new file, use the `-w` flag:

```sh
$ tshark -r input.pcap -Y http -w modified.pcap
```

### Export files

You can also [export](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChIOExportSection.html) certain types of plaintext objects from tshark

```sh
$ output_folder="files"
$ tshark -r input.pcap --export-object http,$output_folder
$ ls $output_folder
example.png example.html ...
```

[This article](https://tshark.dev/export/export_regular/) will walk you through generating a packet capture from which you can then export HTTP files.